# Where should one place CSS stylesheets when using the reactable package in R?

Tags: css, r, rstudio

I'm struggling to understand where to place CSS stylesheets when using the `reactable` package in R. I've read through much of the [package's documentation](https://glin.github.io/reactable/index.html), but it's not clear to me where to store stylesheets.

For example, I see that [this example](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/nba-box-score/nba-box-score.html) on the documentation page has a stylesheet section, but there's no indication where it should be stored so an R script can access it. I'm currently using RStudio's viewer to run code locally and make updates from there, but any CfSS I add via a separate stylesheet fails to connect. I've created Shiny apps in the past that access stylesheets via a `www` folder in the project directory, but that's not working for me in this instance either.

I'm sure this is a straightforward fix, but I'm new to building webpages so I'm a bit in the dark. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If this works similar to R Shiny projects, then:

1. place your css file in the `/www` folder of your project, e.g. `www/styles.css`
2. then make a reference to it in your R file:

```r
tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "styles.css")
```

Comment: Thanks. It still doesn't seem to be working... Do you know if it matters _where_ in the R code I place the reference? That is, before or after the `reactable()` command?